# How to calculate reflection coefficient of a transmission line with discontinuity

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, reflection, reflection-coefficient

I have a question, let's say that we want to calculate the Reflection Coefficient that we see by watching from left to right of the red-line this circuit:
[image]

Let's say that:

```
Za= Equivalent Impedence of the circuit to the right of the red-line
Zb= Equivalent Impedence of the circuit to the left of the red-line
```

My question is which of these is the formula of Γ:

1. Γ=(Za-Zb)/(Za+Zb) (Teacher told me that this isn't the answes but I'm not sure)
2. Γ=(Za-Z1)/(Za+Z1)
3. Γ=(Zb-Z2)/(Zb+Z2)

What is the correct formula for calculate Γ?Why? Why the first of the three possible answer is not correct?